# Prosody XMPP server with onion domain

Tags: onion-routing, torsocks

I set up the XMPP Prosody server in conjunction with the onion domain, it works fine with v2 domains, but when I trying to configure it with onion v3, it does not connect. Everything is clear in prosody logs, there are no errors, but the jabber client simply does not connect.
For v2, I used this

```
sudo apt install tor prosody
printf "HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/jabber\nHiddenServicePort 5222 127.0.0.1:5222\nHiddenServicePort 5322 127.0.0.1:5322\nHiddenServicePort 5269 127.0.0.1:5269\n" | sudo tee /etc/tor/torrc
sudo service tor restart
sudo nano /etc/prosody/prosody.cfg.lua //configuing host
sudo openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out "/etc/prosody/certs/host.crt" -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout "/etc/prosody/certs/host.key"
sudo service prosody restart
```

after that just adding users and it works fine.
On client (pidgin) i set SOCKS5, port 9050
OS ubuntu 16.04, I also tried it on 18 and 20, the result is the same.
What could be the problem and in what direction should you look for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, it was necessary to update the Tor service from the torproject.org repository on the client computers.

Comment: You can mark your answer as correct because it solved the problem.